# How can I achieve a non-clickable page background with OpenX?

Tags: advertisements

I'm trying to reproduce [this](http://allocine.fr) with OpenX. The goal is to have a background set to the body of the page through javascript based on rules given in OpenX.

Comment: Your link has no background on Firefox.

Comment: @Hyppy : please make sure your ad blocker is disabled if you had one, I had the same problem.

Comment: Ahh, got it.  I'm still not sure what is meant by "non-clickable". I could pull it up just fine: http://a69.g.akamai.net/n/69/10688/v1/img4.allocine.fr/acmedia/images/banners/hab_hp_rio_aujourdhui.jpg

Comment: @Hyppy : I mean that clicking on the link does not link to another page Thanks for this link by the way.